# Sharepoint 2010 to 2013 Migration: site collection won't appear even after detaching/reattaching content DB

Tags: sharepoint-server, site-collection, migration, orphan

I cannot for the life of me get a site collection to appear after attaching the database.

Running into a problem that I can't find a solution for.

I'm migrating a 2010 SP install to 2013, and I'm running into this constant problem concerning my site collection -- the only site collection -- not being able to connect. It's giving me this error about not being found in the site map:

[image]

When I perform a stsadm -o -enumallwebs, it shows the one and only site collection and states that 'InsiteMap="False"'.

I've tried detatching/reattaching the database with no success.

I've also reconstructed this numerous times. Deleting the web application, resolving every error in Test-SPContentDatabase (which was a chore since its been around since 2007), backing up/restoring the DB, detatching the DB from 2010 and reattaching in 2013 -- I'm puzzled.

Any ideas on what I could be missing here? Is there a way to maybe reconnect an orphaned site (the only site) back to the web application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out my problem: I can't have a web application that has the same name as the site collection, and the site is a host-header site, so configuration is a bit different than path-based sites.

I wrote more information here, if anyone is interested: http://www.consentfactory.com/migrating-sharepoint-2010-to-2013/